# How to let Mercurial ignore every thing except *.cs file?

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg, hgignore

I started a project and added it to Mercurial. But I want to take `*.cs` file under version control only. So I have to add `bin`, `obj`, `sln`, `suo`, `_resharper` folder etc to ignore pattern.

How to let Hg only monitor certain kind of file like white list? How to do that in Subversion?

Comment: Mercurial or Subversion or both?

Comment: Only Mercurial is ok, both if know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add the extensions to your `.hgignore` file as you come across them:

```
syntax: glob
*.bin
*.obj
```

and so on. It's not a lot of work, and it documents to the rest of the world exactly what kind of files you consider unimportant for revision control.

You can even setup a global ignore file, please see the [`ignore` entry in the `[ui]` section](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#ui).

Trying to turn the `.hgignore` upside-down by using negative lookahead regular expressions and other voodoo is (in my opinion) not a good idea. It will almost surely not work and will only lead to confusion. This is because `hg` matches all prefixes of a give path name against the [rules in `.hgignore`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html). So a file like

```
a/b/c.cs
```

will be ignored if any of

```
a/b/c.cs
a/b
a
```

is matched by a rule in your `.hgignore` file. In particular, this means that you cannot use a negative lookahead expression to have `a/b/c.cs` not-ignored -- the rule will match `a/b` or `a`.

Comment: So you're saying that there's no negation operator?

Comment: Mike: Yes, unfortunately. Please see this issue http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/issue712 where you can leave a comment if you're very interested.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the link to a Mercurial issue supplied by Martin Geisler (https://www.mercurial-scm.org/bts/issue712), please note that the issue is not one of technical difficulty, but support:

> *This is an ancient and recurring feature request, which I turned down well
>   before this bug was created. I've written and supported a couple
>   include/exclude file syntaxes and have decided I would rather say "no, you
>   can't do that" once to 1% of users than "no, you're reading the docs wrong"
>   repeatedly to 20% of users.* —Matt Mackall (developer of Mercurial)

Answer (score -2):

Add a file named `.hgignore` to your repository with these contents.

```
syntax: regexp

^\.cs
```

Subversion doesn't let you use regex to ignore files, only a subset of [glob syntax](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13) to match file/directory names. I had no idea how to make ignore files not ending in .cs so I searched the web and [this webpage](http://www.thoughtspark.org/node/38) says:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "*[!c][!s]
*.cs?*" .
```

Use it with caution :)

Edit: Martin Geisler is right and I was mistaken, the regexp syntax is wrong. I apologize. The correct concept is there but not the metacharacters... :(

Comment: The `^\.cs` regexp will make `hg` ignore a file called `.cs` in the root directory of the repository. It wont make `hg` ignore all files *not* matching `*.cs` (glob pattern).